# Expecting a single value error in kmcudaR

Tags: r, gpu

When I try to cluster `samples` into 50 clusters using kmcudaR as follows, I get this error:

```
samples = replicate(4, runif(16000))

kmeans_cuda(samples, 50)

Error in r_kmeans_cuda(samples, clusters, tolerance, init, yinyang_t,  : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=0].
```

What does this error mean in this context? Other questions have been asked about this in R, but all of the answers provide alternate solutions, not a solution to the particular error.

Thanks!

Comment: Try one of the examples in the package tests `kmeans_cuda(samples, 50, tolerance=0.01, init="random", seed=777, verbosity=0)`